# Remove Light Switch - Bury or Move?

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I have an interesting concern. I bought a house built in 1978, and since then the previous owners made some changes. One of which I can't figure out how to do safely and up to code. And I have read about a dozen similar questions on here to try to ensure I am not doubling up.

I have a closet in a bedroom, with a separate light to the rest of the room. Now, the closet has a switch for the light in the hallway - through a wall. My question is would it be easier to move the switch (about 8") and place it within the closet? Or just to tie it off and use the "pull switch" that they put on the fixture? As a side note, I am in Alberta, Canada - if you know what code issues I may run into that would also be greatly appreciated insights.

And leaving it to me isn't an option, I don't like the switch in the hallway for a variety of reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you okay with a blank cover plate instead of a switch in the current location, or do you want to cover it with drywall?  If you want to cover it, you have to move it, since all junction boxes must remain accessible by code.

Comment: Burying is out of the question as burying a junction box is completely illegal.  Also, most likely your Code requires that a light switch be in the usual location.

Comment: @NateStrickland, ideally, I would find a way to "bury" bury it. If I have to for now, I will be fine with a cover plate. But that still leaves me with the issue down the road, when we reno that room (years from now). 

As for the wiring, can I just pull out the switch and go black to black, white to white, etc? Would that work?

Comment: @JCrosby, it depends how it was wired originally.  If it was panel->switch->light then yes, that should work (assuming you've got the standard cable color coding).  If it's panel->light->switch, then you'd instead join black to white (or rewire at the light fixture to connect it directly to power there).  Look up "switch loop".

Comment: @Harper, that's true if it's an actively used junction box, but if it's an abandoned switch loop disconnected at both ends, I think it'd be fine to bury, right?  And I think a pull chain at the fixture counts as a "usual location" for a closet light switch in most jurisdictions.

Comment: @NateStrickland the wire should be removed as far as possible, and the junction box should absolutely be removed. It must be obvious to whoever digs this up later that it was intentionally abandoned.

Comment: @Harper, so if I want to remove the box, I can if I remove the wiring as far as possible. However, how can I remove the wiring if, that is the only path for power to the light? Which is how it appears.

Comment: Nate asked about a switch loop.  Your example would not be that: in your case the junction box is **in use** and is not abandoned at all.  You can relocate the junction box to anywhere the wires can reach with the minimum wire length entering the box (6" or 3" beyond wall surface whichever is greater), but the box must remain unless you want to replace both cable runs with one new cable run.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help - sorry about repeating his question I am still learning some of the jargon and didn't realize I had.

Comment: Would it be inappropriate to use the Tyco NM cable in-wall splice product to eliminate the switch and j-box?

Comment: @GregHill Usually, yes.  You have to closely look at the enabling Code which authorizes that device, but IIRC they amended it I believe in 2014 to say it's for repairs only, not remodel.